# calling a template function of the base class

Tags: c++, templates, linker

```
class Base
{
  protected:
    template<typename TFunc>
    void m_vProcess(TFunc& func) const
    {
         BasePrivateClass<TFunc> baseprivateobj(func);
         // rest of code              
    }

   private:   
       template<typename TFunc>
       class BasePrivateClass
       {
       public:
           BasePrivateClass(TFunc& obj) :m_obj(oParam)
           {}                            
        private:  
           TFunc& m_obj;
   };
};
```

and this is my derived class:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
private:
   class DerivedPrivateClass
    {
    public:
        explicit DerivedPrivateClass(int **p): m_objDerived(poParam)
        {}
    private:
         int** m_objDerived;
    };
};
```

From a function in class Derived, I try this:

```
DerivedPrivateClass obj(param);
this->m_vProcess(obj);
```

---

I get a linker error of multiply defined symbols - symbols are defined in both base and derived class.

I have no idea what causes the linker error. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the linker error?

Comment: @Alon : Symbols are multiply defined. Many functions/variables of the base class are present in the object files of both base and derived.

Comment: You miss ; at the end of the class declerations

Comment: i have it in the code...i missed it while framing the question here...apologies...will edit and put them...

Comment: I would try to post a simplified question, perhaps create a sample, instead of, what is wrong in this code..

Comment: edited the question with only the necessary details..hope it is fine now...

Answer (score 0):

As I commented.. a bit hard to read.. but from the looks of it, a main issue would be that the m_vProcessAnimParams function you are trying to use is private in Base, so Dervied cannot access it..